# How can i pass library in BaseController to any Controller's constructer in codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, construct

i want use codeigniter's uri library in multiple pages.For this reason i created an instance of uri library in BaseController with named `$uri`. I can use this library in my `Home::index controller` but i can not use in `Home::__construct`.  Any suggestion?

BaseController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use CodeIgniter\Controller;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\CLIRequest;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\IncomingRequest;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;


/**
 * Class BaseController
 *
 * BaseController provides a convenient place for loading components
 * and performing functions that are needed by all your controllers.
 * Extend this class in any new controllers:
 *     class Home extends BaseController
 *
 * For security be sure to declare any new methods as protected or private.
 */
class BaseController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Instance of the main Request object.
     *
     * @var CLIRequest|IncomingRequest
     */
    protected $request;

    /**
     * An array of helpers to be loaded automatically upon
     * class instantiation. These helpers will be available
     * to all other controllers that extend BaseController.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $helpers = ["cookie"];

    protected $session;
    protected $parser;
    protected $uri;


    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public function initController(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        // Do Not Edit This Line
        parent::initController($request, $response, $logger);

        // Preload any models, libraries, etc, here.
        $this->session      = \Config\Services::session();
        $this->parser       = \Config\Services::parser();
        // $this->uri          = new \CodeIgniter\HTTP\URI(current_url(true));
        $this->uri          = service('uri');
        $this->uri->setSilent();

    // Preload any models, libraries, etc, here.

    // E.g.: $this->session = \Config\Services::session();

    }
}
```

Home.php

```
class Home extends BaseController
{
    public function __construct()
      {
        var_dump($this->uri);//line 16
      }
    public function index()
      {
        die(var_dump($this->uri));//line 21
    }
}
```

var_dumps

```
C:\wamp64\www\ci4\app\Controllers\Home.php:16:null
C:\wamp64\www\ci4\app\Controllers\Home.php:21:
object(CodeIgniter\HTTP\URI)[11]
  protected 'uriString' => null
  protected 'segments' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'scheme' => string 'http' (length=4)
  protected 'user' => null
  protected 'password' => null
  protected 'host' => string 'localhost' (length=9)
  protected 'port' => null
  protected 'path' => string '/' (length=1)
  protected 'fragment' => string '' (length=0)
  protected 'query' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'defaultPorts' => 
    array (size=4)
      'http' => int 80
      'https' => int 443
      'ftp' => int 21
      'sftp' => int 22
  protected 'showPassword' => boolean false
  protected 'silent' => boolean true
  protected 'rawQueryString' => boolean false
```

Comment: You need to call `initController()` before you can use those properties. Where and when is the method `initController()` suppose to be called? And why not have that code in the constructor instead?

Comment: initController() is codeigniter 4 default constructor function. Edited BaseController.php